# Finding complex root in Fortran

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers

i found some sources where algorithms are suggested to determine complex roots in general analytic functions (no polynomials). E.g. "A Fortran program for solving a nonlinear equation by Muller's
method", written by I. Barrodale and K. B. Wilson. Unfortunately the code is only available in pdf format and the transfer to ASCII is quite cumbersome... And also Henning Bach, Volume 121, Number 12, page 675-678, December 1969. Its available in ASCII. The letter one works fine but is quite slow for my purpose. Is there a standard routine for computing complex roots in Fortran?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ones who are interested. I took the one from I. Barrodale and K. B. Wilson. Since the article is free to read online, I wanna post the code here. It is by far the fastest and most reliable I found. To use it, define a subroutine calcf(x,f). f is the function value for x. x and f are complex.

for more Information -> http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0771050X78900414

This is the version for double precision:

```
SUBROUTINE ROOTS(KNOWN,NMORE,KM,REALRT,EP1,EP2,GUESS,MAXITS,RTS,NFOUND, FNV, IFAIL)

COMPLEX*16 RTS(KM), FNV(KM), X1, X2, X3, F1, F2, F3, &
X21, X32, F21, F32, F31, F321, B, XNEW, FNEW, DENOM, &
FSAVE, CSQRT, RADICL, RT, DIF, CSTEP, FSLAST
REAL*8 EP1, EP2, ONE, HUNDRD, TWO, FOUR, HALF, STEP, &
ZERO, EP1DEF, EP2DEF
INTEGER GUESS
LOGICAL REALRT
DATA IZERO,IONE,ITWO,ITHREE,ZERO,HALF,ONE,TWO,FOUR,HUNDRD,ITSDEF,EP1DEF,EP2DEF &
/0,1,2,3,0.0d0,0.5d0,1.0d0,2.0d0,4.0d0,100.0d0,100,0.5d-5,1.0d-6/
EP1 = AMAX1(EP1,EP1DEF)
EP2 = AMAX1(EP2,EP2DEF)
MAXITS = MIN0(MAXITS,ITSDEF)
IFAIL = IZERO
NFOUND = IZERO
IF (KNOWN.LT.IONE) GO TO 30
DO 10 I=1,KNOWN
II = I
CALL CALCF(RTS(I), FNV(I))
IF (ABS(FNV(II)).GE.EP2) GO TO 20
10 CONTINUE
20 IFAIL =IONE
GUESS = GUESS + KNOWN - II +IONE
NMORE = NMORE + KNOWN - II +IONE
KNOWN = II - IONE
30 CONTINUE
LOOP1 = KNOWN +IONE
LOOP2 = KNOWN + NMORE
IF (LOOP1.GT.LOOP2 .OR. LOOP1.LT.IONE) GO TO 180
IF (GUESS-NMORE) 40, 70, 60
40 ILO = GUESS + IONE
DO 50 I=ILO,LOOP2
RTS(I) = ZERO
50 CONTINUE
GO TO 70
60 CONTINUE
GUESS = NMORE
70 CONTINUE
STEP = HALF
DO 160 NEW=LOOP1,LOOP2
KOUNT = ITHREE
NEWM1 = NEW - IONE
RT = RTS(NEW)
X1 = RT - STEP
X2 = RT + STEP
X3 = RT
CALL CALCF(X1, F1)
CALL CALCF(X2, F2)
CALL CALCF(X3, F3)
FSLAST = F3
IF (NEW.GT.IONE) CALL TEST(X1, F1, FSAVE, RTS,NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
IF (NEW.GT.IONE) CALL TEST(X2, F2, FSAVE, RTS,NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
IF (NEW.GT.IONE) CALL TEST(X3, F3, FSLAST, RTS,NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
F21 = (F2-F1)/(X2-X1)
80 X32 = X3 - X2
F32 = (F3-F2)/X32
F321 = (F32-F21)/(X3-X1)
B = F32 + X32*F321
RADICL = B**ITWO - FOUR*F321*F3
IF (REALRT .AND. REAL(RADICL).LT.ZERO) RADICL = ZERO
RADICL = SQRT(RADICL)
IF (REAL(B)*REAL(RADICL)+AIMAG(B)*AIMAG(RADICL).LT.ZERO) RADICL = -RADICL
DENOM = B + RADICL
IF (ABS(DENOM).NE.ZERO) GO TO 100
IF (ABS(F3).GE.EP2) GO TO 90
XNEW = X3
GO TO 120
90 XNEW = X3 + X32
GO TO 120
100 CSTEP = TWO*F3/DENOM
IF (.NOT.REALRT .OR. ABS(F3).EQ.ZERO .OR. ABS(F32).EQ.ZERO) GO TO 110
CSTEP = F32/ABS(F32)*F3/ABS(F3)*ABS(CSTEP)
110 XNEW = X3 - CSTEP
120 CALL CALCF(XNEW, FNEW)
FSAVE = FNEW
IF (NEW.LE.IONE) GO TO 130
CALL TEST(XNEW, FNEW, FSAVE, RTS, NEWM1, EP2,KOUNT)
130 KOUNT = KOUNT +IONE
IF (KOUNT.GT.MAXITS) GO TO 170
DIF = XNEW - X3
IF (ABS(DIF).LT.EP1*ABS(XNEW)) GO TO 150
IF (ABS(FSAVE).LT.EP2) GO TO 150
IF (REALRT .OR. ABS(FSAVE).LT.HUNDRD*ABS(FSLAST)) GO TO 140
CSTEP = CSTEP*HALF
XNEW = XNEM + CSTEP
GO TO 120
140 X1 = X2
X2 = X3
X3 = XNEW
F1 = F2
F2 = F3
F3 = FNEW
FSLAST = FSAVE
F21 = F32
GO TO 80
150 CONTINUE
RTS(NEW) = XNEW
FNV(NEW) = FSAVE
NFOUND = NEW
160 CONTINUE
GO TO 190
170 CONTINUE
RTS(NEW) = XNEW
FNV(NEW) = FSAVE
IFAIL = ITHREE
GO TO 190
180 CONTINUE
IFAIL = ITWO
190 CONTINUE
RETURN
END

SUBROUTINE TEST(X, F, FSAVE, RTS, K, EPS, KOUNT)
COMPLEX*16 X, F, RTS(K), D, FSAVE
REAL*8 EPS!, CABS
DATA IONE, PERTB /1,0.01d0/
10 CONTINUE
DO 20 I=1,K
D = X - RTS(I)
IF (ABS(D).LE.EPS) GO TO 30
F = F/D
20 CONTINUE
GO TO 40
30 CONTINUE
X = X + PERTB
CALL CALCF(X, F)
FSAVE = F
KOUNT = KOUNT +IONE
GO TO 10
40 RETURN
END
```

Comment: you really shouldnt do this .. Articles published under an Elsevier user license are protected by copyright. Users may access, download, copy, translate, text and data mine (but *may not redistribute, display or adapt*)

Answer (score 2):

I have revised the ROOTS subroutine, and adapted it for gfortran (e.g. REALPART and IMAGPART for complex variables). Also corrected an error in the source code posted by KELLEKAI, i.e. XNEW = XNEM + CSTEP, which obviously should be XNEW = XNEW + CSTEP (this is why IMPLICIT NONE is preferable). Original comments are also included. I tested the subroutine for a nonlinear equation with multiple complex roots and it works fine.

```
C source code from I. Barrodale and K. B. Wilson,
C "A Fortran program for solving a nonlinear equation by Muller's method"
C Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, vol. 4, no. 2, 1978
cccccCcccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxccCCCCCCCC
      SUBROUTINE ROOTS(KNOWN, NMORE, KM, REALRT, EP1, EP2,              ROO   10
     & GUESS, MAXITS, RTS, NFOUND, FNV, IFAIL)                          ROO   20
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C   The user must supply a subprogram as follows
C       SUBROUTINE CALCF (X, F)
C   where X and F are complex numbers, X is an independent variable
C   and F is the corresponding function value.
C-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C
C   This subroutine uses Muller's method to find roots (real or complex)
C   of a general equation
C
C   Description of parameters:
C
C   KNOWN   an INTEGER denoting the number of roots already known.
C           If the function value for one of these "known" roots
C           is not "small" the value of known is reset to the last
C           index of a root with a small function value, and the
C           remaining "known" roots are recalculated.
C   NMORE   an INTEGER denoting the number of roots to be found
C           (i.e. in addition to those already known).
C           NMORE is reset to account for the case when KNOWN is reset.
C   KM      an INTEGER used to define dimensions.
C           KM must be set at least (KNOWN + NMORE)
C   REALRT  a LOGICAL variable with values as follows:
C           .TRUE. indicates that only REAL roots are to be found
C               (i.e. complex numbers with zero imaginary parts)
C           .FALSE. indicates that complex roots are to be found
C   EP1     a small positive real number denoting the "first"
C           convergence criterion: if at the K-th stage the relative
C           change in two successive approximations to a root is less
C           than EP1, convergence is said to have taken place
C           (i.e. the absolute value of (ROOT(K)-ROOT(K-1))/ROOT(K)
C           is less than EP1 the convergence occurs). See below for
C           minimum default values
C   EP2     a small positive real number denoting the "second"
C           convergence criterion: if at anu stage the absolute value
C           of the function is less than EP2, convergence is said to
C           have taken place. See below for minimum default values.
C           EP2 is also used by SUBROUTINE TEST to determine if a
C           current approximation is "close" to a root already identified
C   GUESS   an INTEGER denoting the number of roots for which the user
C           is supplying estimates. GUESS is reset to account for the
C           case when KNOWN is reset. Also, GUESS must not exceed NMORE.
C   MAXITS  an INTEGER denoting the maximum number of function calls
C           allowed when finding any root. If MAXITS function evaluations
C           are performed the subroutine "fails" and return control to
C           the user. The roots already found and the last approximation
C           to the root causing "failure" are stored in RTS. See below
C           for maximum default values.
C   RTS     a COMPLEX vector of length at least KM:
C           On entry if any roots are available they must be in
C           positions 1 to KNOWN of RTS.
C           On entry, if estimates of the roots to be found are known,
C           (i.e. GUESS.GT.ZERO) they must be in positions
C           (KNOWN+1) to (KNOWN + GUESS).
C           On return the roots of the equation are stored in the first
C           NFOUND positions. If "failure" due to MAXITS return, the
C           (NFOUND+1) position of RTS contains the last approximation
C           to the root which caused the "failure".
C   NFOUND  an INTEGER denoting the number of roots now known and
C           stored in RTS.
C   FNV     a COMPLEX vector of length at least KM containing the
C           function values associated with the vector RTS.
C   IFAIL   an integer exit code with values as follows:
C           0 indicates all roots were found as requested by the user
C           1 indicates (as above) all roots were found but in addition
C             some of the input "known" roots were recalculated
C           2 if the input parameters KNOWN or NMORE satisfy the
C             following: KNOWN.LT.0, NMORE.LT.1 control is returned
C             immediately to the user
C           3 if MAXITS causes "failure" control is returned
C             immediately to the user
cccccCcccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxccCCCCCCCC
      INTEGER KNOWN, NMORE, KM, GUESS, MAXITS, NFOUND, IFAIL            ROO   30
      COMPLEX*16 RTS(KM), FNV(KM), X1, X2, X3, F1, F2, F3,              ROO   40
     & X21, X32, F21, F32, F31, F321, B, XNEW, FNEW, DENOM,             ROO   50
     & FSAVE, CSQRT, RADICL, RT, DIF, CSTEP, FSLAST                     ROO   60
      REAL*8 EP1, EP2, ONE, HUNDRD, TWO, FOUR, HALF, STEP,              ROO   70
     & ZERO, EP1DEF, EP2DEF                                             ROO   80
      LOGICAL REALRT                                                    ROO   90
      DATA IZERO, IONE, ITWO, ITHREE, ZERO, HALF, ONE, TWO,             ROO  100
     & FOUR, HUNDRD, ITSDEF, EP1DEF, EP2DEF                             ROO  110
     & /0,1,2,3,0.0d0,0.5d0,1.0d0,2.0d0,4.0d0,100.0d0,100,              ROO  120
     & 0.5D-6,1.0D-7/                                                   ROO  130
C
C   Initialization
C   Check for errors in the input and set default values if necessary
C
      EP1 = DMAX1(EP1,EP1DEF)
      EP2 = DMAX1(EP2,EP2DEF)
      MAXITS = MIN0(MAXITS,ITSDEF)
      IFAIL = IZERO
      NFOUND = IZERO
      IF (KNOWN.LT.IONE) GO TO 30
      DO 10 I=1,KNOWN
      II = I
      CALL CALCF(RTS(I), FNV(I))
C   no record is kept of the number of function evaluations
C   used here to ckeck the list of known roots
      IF (ABS(FNV(II)).GE.EP2) GO TO 20
10    CONTINUE
20    IFAIL =IONE
      GUESS = GUESS + KNOWN - II +IONE
      NMORE = NMORE + KNOWN - II +IONE
      KNOWN = II - IONE
30    CONTINUE
      LOOP1 = KNOWN +IONE
      LOOP2 = KNOWN + NMORE
      IF (LOOP1.GT.LOOP2 .OR. LOOP1.LT.IONE) GO TO 180
      IF (GUESS-NMORE) 40, 70, 60
40    ILO = GUESS + IONE
      DO 50 I=ILO,LOOP2
        RTS(I) = ZERO
50    CONTINUE
      GO TO 70
60    CONTINUE
      GUESS = NMORE
70    CONTINUE
      STEP = HALF
C
C   try to find NMORE roots in this major loop
      DO 160 NEW=LOOP1,LOOP2
        KOUNT = ITHREE
        NEWM1 = NEW - IONE
        RT = RTS(NEW)
        X1 = RT - STEP
        X2 = RT + STEP
        X3 = RT
C   use first estimates
        CALL CALCF(X1, F1)
        CALL CALCF(X2, F2)
        CALL CALCF(X3, F3)
        FSLAST = F3
        IF (NEW.GT.IONE)
     &  CALL TEST(X1, F1, FSAVE,  RTS, NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
        IF (NEW.GT.IONE)
     &  CALL TEST(X2, F2, FSAVE,  RTS, NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
        IF (NEW.GT.IONE)
     &  CALL TEST(X3, F3, FSLAST, RTS, NEWM1, EP2, KOUNT)
        F21 = (F2-F1)/(X2-X1)
C   find the roots of the quadratic
80      X32 = X3 - X2
        F32 = (F3-F2)/X32
        F321 = (F32-F21)/(X3-X1)
        B = F32 + X32*F321
        RADICL = B**ITWO - FOUR*F321*F3
        IF (REALRT .AND. REALPART(RADICL) .LT. ZERO) RADICL = ZERO
        RADICL = CDSQRT(RADICL)
        IF (
     &    (REALPART(B)*REALPART(RADICL)+IMAGPART(B)*IMAGPART(RADICL)
     &     ) .LT. ZERO) RADICL = -RADICL
        DENOM = B + RADICL
        IF (ABS(DENOM).NE.ZERO) GO TO 100
        IF (ABS(F3).GE.EP2) GO TO 90
        XNEW = X3
        GO TO 120
90      XNEW = X3 + X32
        GO TO 120
100     CSTEP = TWO*F3/DENOM
        IF (.NOT. REALRT .OR. ABS(F3) .EQ. ZERO .OR.
     &  ABS(F32) .EQ. ZERO) GO TO 110
        CSTEP = F32/ABS(F32)*F3/ABS(F3)*ABS(CSTEP)
110     XNEW = X3 - CSTEP
120     CALL CALCF(XNEW, FNEW)
        FSAVE = FNEW
        IF (NEW.LE.IONE) GO TO 130
        CALL TEST(XNEW, FNEW, FSAVE, RTS, NEWM1, EP2,KOUNT)
130     KOUNT = KOUNT +IONE
C   test iterations, convergence and divergence
        IF (KOUNT.GT.MAXITS) GO TO 170
        DIF = XNEW - X3
        IF (ABS(DIF).LT.EP1*ABS(XNEW)) GO TO 150
        IF (ABS(FSAVE).LT.EP2) GO TO 150
        IF (REALRT .OR. ABS(FSAVE) .LT. HUNDRD*ABS(FSLAST))
     &  GO TO 140
C   divergence "fix"
        CSTEP = CSTEP*HALF
        XNEW = XNEW + CSTEP
        GO TO 120
140     X1 = X2
        X2 = X3
        X3 = XNEW
        F1 = F2
        F2 = F3
        F3 = FNEW
        FSLAST = FSAVE
        F21 = F32
        GO TO 80
150     CONTINUE
C   convergence to one more root
C   (the number of function evaluations used in determining the current root
C   is available at this stage; output the variable KOUNT if desired)
        write(*,*) ' number function evaluations = ', KOUNT
        RTS(NEW) = XNEW
        FNV(NEW) = FSAVE
        NFOUND = NEW
160     CONTINUE
        GO TO 190
170     CONTINUE
C   MAXITS reached
        RTS(NEW) = XNEW
        FNV(NEW) = FSAVE
        IFAIL = ITHREE
        GO TO 190
180   CONTINUE
      IFAIL = ITWO
190   CONTINUE
      RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE ROOTS

cccccCcccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxcccccccccxccCCCCCCCC
      SUBROUTINE TEST(X, F, FSAVE, RTS, K, EPS, KOUNT)                  TES   10
C
C This subroutine serves two purposes:
C   1. Deflation of the function is performed,
C       i.e. if X is the current approximation to a root
C       and RTS is a vector of roots already known, the
C       deflated function value is
C       F=(...((F.(X-RTS(1)))/(X-RTS(2)))/...)
C   2. If a current approximation to a root is "too close"
C       to a root already known, X is perturbed away from
C       the known root by 0.01. This device avoids division
C       by (essentially) zero in the deflation process, but it
C       does not prevent convergence to multiple zeros.
C
      COMPLEX*16 X, F, RTS(K), D, FSAVE                                 TES   20
      REAL*8 EPS, PERTB                                                 TES   30
      DATA IONE, PERTB /1, 0.01D0/                                      TES   40
10    CONTINUE                                                          TES   50
      DO 20 I=1,K                                                       TES   60
        D = X - RTS(I)                                                  TES   70
        IF (ABS(D) .LE. EPS) GO TO 30                                   TES   80
        F = F/D                                                         TES   90
20    CONTINUE                                                          TES  100
      GO TO 40                                                          TES  110
30    CONTINUE                                                          TES  120
      X = X + PERTB                                                     TES  130
      CALL CALCF(X, F)                                                  TES  140
      FSAVE = F                                                         TES  150
      KOUNT = KOUNT + IONE                                              TES  160
      GO TO 10                                                          TES  170
40    RETURN                                                            TES  180
      END SUBROUTINE TEST                                               TES  190
```